# Как расставить знаки препинания в предложении "Dog — по-английски собака"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли закавычить слово "dog"? А слово "собака"? Может быть тире не нужно? Или нужно, но не там?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Сказала миссис Эйбл:
Стол по-английски ... table

Просил повесить полку шеф.
А полка по-английски ... shelf".

Dog - по-английски собака. (Dog - это собака на английском языке). Кавычки не нужны, слово выделяется записью на другом языке.

Также возможен вариант: Dog - по-английски "собака".

Comment: Ага, спасибо. А если наоборот? "Собака" по-английски -- dog?

Comment: Да, это правильная запись. Пауза в устной речи и тире на письме обязательны - они относят наречие  "по-английски" к слову "собака".

Answer (score 1):

Тире не нужно. Если между подлежащим и сказуемым, которые выражены существительными в именительном падеже, стоит наречие, тире опускается. На паузы ориентироваться нельзя: не все паузы обозначаются знаками препинания и не все знаки препинания совпадают с паузами. Например, деепричастные обороты и придаточные предложения произносятся без пауз, а запятыми выделяются.

Comment: В пунктуации действуют два принципа: грамматический и интонационный, иногда они дополняют друг друг, а в некоторых случаях действует один принцип - в частности, паузы могут не обозначаться запятыми. Что касается этой темы, то здесь наличие паузы - это окончательная проверка вашего решения, совпадение пауз и запятых ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО.

Comment: При наличии наречий тире/пауза отсутствует в тех случаях, если наречие относится и к подлежащему,  и сказуемому, например:Туризм для меня лучший отдых.   Стихи для вас одна забава.  В этих случаях не стоит задача отделить состав подлежащего от состава сказуемого, но иногда это необходимо: Дождь летом – одно удовольствие. Минута с ней – небесный рай. Самая лучшая защита для меня – ясное спокойствие души. в нашем примере такая задача как раз стоит: наречие относится к слову "собака"

Comment: Мне кажется, постановка тире в ваших примерах субъективна, зависит от авторского смысла. Большинство примеров не имеют отношения к наречиям. Ну да ладно. 
Дождь летом - одно удовольствие (летний дождь). Дождь летом одно удовольствие (а осенью огорчение). Почему "Собака по-английски - dog"? С чего вы взяли, что эта пауза в устной речи обязательна? Можно ссылочку на учебник о паузах? Действительно, от критериев обязательности пауз зависит понимание многих правил. Это важно.

Comment: Если рассмотреть тему "Тире между подлежащим и сказумым", то становится понятно, что только один вариант имеет однозначное решение - постановка тире при наличии слов-связок ЭТО, ЗНАЧИТ, ЭТО ЗНАЧИТ. Во всех других случаях на каждое "тире пишется" найдется исключение "тире не пишется", поэтому можно сказать, что субъективность решения здесь закономерна, а наличие паузы в речи является своеобразной проверкой.

Comment: Интонация в средней школе практически не изучается, поэтому приходится просто слушать текст. Попробуем не поставить тире: "собака по-английски dog".  Смысл достаточно понятен, но интонация совершенно бесцветная - неясно, где делать перелом тональности. Теперь поставим тире: "Собака (повышение тона) по-английски (пауза) - dog". Теперь интонация становится ясной, и что важно - интонационное (и логическое)  ударение падает на слова "собака" и  "dog, которые и сравниваются в этом случае.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но все-таки: будет ли ошибкой вариант без тире? Однозначного указания на это в правилах пунктуации не нахожу.